# Include image based where in the sub-tree a page is

Tags: typo3, typoscript

Assume I have the following page tree:

```
root
|
|__ tree_a
|  |
|  |_ site_1
|    |
|    |_ site_2
|
|__ tree_b
   |
   |_ site_2
   |_ site_3
```

For each of the first-level sub-trees (i.e., `tree_a`, `tree_b`), different images should be shown in a fixed location on the page. I'm doing this with TemplaVoila!, but the problem is more general.

How can I, in TypoScript, conditionally insert an image depending on where in the tree I am?

For example, when I'm on `site_1` or `site_2`, I'd like to include the image `tree_a.png`. And from `site_2` and `site_3`, the image `tree_b.png`.

I'm thinking I'll have to use a `HMENU` and `browse` it somehow, but this is way over my head at my current stage of learning TypoScript (first day).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest you to use [`KB TV Content Slide`](http://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/kb_tv_cont_slide) extension which is dedicated exactly for that what you need.

For an example you are setting image in some mapped element in `Tree A` and it's inherited on all subpages, at least until you'll replace it with other element.